# Are $ \sum_{n\ge1}f(n)\quad \text{and}\quad \left(\int^n_1f(t)\cdot dt\right)_n $ of the same nature?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $f:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $\displaystyle \int_1^{+\infty}|f'(t)|\cdot dt$ converges
>
> Show that these both series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge1}f(n)\quad (*) \quad \text{and}\quad \left(\int^n_1f(t)\cdot dt\right)_n \quad (**)\quad  $ are of the same nature.

I spent time trying to prove that :

if $(*)$ diverges then $(**)$ diverges

if $(*)$ converges then $(**)$ converges
and the converse

But the correction suggests to show that the sequence $\displaystyle u_n:=\int^{n+1}_1f(t)\cdot dt-\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)$ converges.

I really don't know why?

Comment: Because once you prove that, you have $\int_0^{n+1} =\sum_1^n + u_n$, and $\lim_n u_n=0$. That will give you the fact that $\int_0^{n+1}$ converges (when $n\to\infty$) iff $\sum_1^n$ converges.

Comment: @ClementC. ok, the sufficient condition for $\int$ and $\sum$ are of the same nature is $\lim u_n=0$ Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let's see what is the error term for the estimate
$$\int_a^b f(t) dt \approx (b-a)\frac{ f(a) + f(b)}{2}$$

Consider the function $g(x) = x - \frac{a+b}{2}$ and do an integration by parts trick
$$\int_a^b f(t) dt = \int_a^b f(t) g'(t) dt = f(x)g(x)\mid_a^b - \int_a ^b f'(t)g(t) dt =\\=(b-a)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} - \int_a^b f'(t) g(t) dt $$

Therefore
$$|\int_a^b f(t) dt - (b-a)\frac{ f(a) + f(b)}{2}| \le \frac{b-a}{2}\int_a ^b |f'(t)| dt$$

Apply this for each segment $[n,n+1]$ and sum up. We get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\int_n^{n+1} f(t) dt - \frac{ f(n) + f(n+1)}{2}|\le \frac{1}{2} \int_1^\infty |f'(t)| dt$$

Comment: But that's not answering the actual question, is it? *"I really don't know why [the correction suggests to prove this]?"*

Comment: @orangeskid It was not the expected answer, but I accept. Thank you Clement C